# a broad range of vs a wide range

Tags: grammaticality

Could you help me to point out the differences in the following sentences. for me both sentences imply same meaning.

> The Restaurant , offers a broad range of locally caught fresh seafood,
>   prime steak and meat dishes
>
> The Restaurant , offers a wide range of locally caught fresh seafood,
>   prime steak and meat dishes

Comment: Remove the comma after _Restaurant_, and add one after _steak_. You could use _local_ instead of _locally caught_; put a comma after _local_. As for _wide_ versus _broad_, it depends on whether you see the _range_ as being a parcel of land (if, use _wide_), or as a roadway (if so, use _broad_); the difference is only metaphoric.

Comment: Sir, if i use wide variety, does it more close to the context of the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by in John Lawyer's comment, there definitely should not be a comma after "Restaurant" and nor should there be a space in front of a comma).

Apart from that, (as a Brit) I see absolutely no difference in meaning between the two sentences:

- I perceive no difference between *wide* and *broad* in this context.
- Nor do I perceive any difference between *range* and *variety* in this context. Personally, I do not think *assortment* (as suggested in another answer) is so appropriate in this context for reasons I find difficult to explain: it just does not seem so idiomatic.)

Being pedantic:

- "Restaurant" should not be capitalised: it is not a proper noun.
- You could say "*other* meat dishes", because "prime steak" is also a meat dish.
- I think a comma after "steak" (as suggested by John Lawyer) would be desirable.

Answer (score 4):

"wide range" seems more natural.  The two words are synonyms: a river can be broad or wide.  In your particular sentence, "wide range" is more commonly used.

A Web search for "broad range" turns up nothing useful; "wide range", at least hundreds of hits.